# How to build a list of composite objects with Express/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, express, mean

I am following a tutorial which only has a simple object model:

```
Customer.getAll = result => {
  sql.query("SELECT * FROM customers", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(null, err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("customers: ", res);
    result(null, res);
  });
};
```

However, I have want my objects to include parent table with child table included. I haven't found a good example of how to accomplish this. Can anyone point me to some good resources on this?

I'd want to return something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Something",
    "type": 1,
    "Values": [
      { "type": "A", "value1": 20, "Value2": 40, "Value3": 0 },
      { "type": "B", "value1": 100, "Value2": 40, "Value3": 0 },
      { "type": "C", "value1": 0, "Value2": 40, "Value3": 30 }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the parent table might be Item, and has a child table called ItemValues. How do I build objects that look like this.

Comment: I think this is not related to MySQL as you have to build object. Parent child nested json object can be build on code side.

Comment: It is more related to processing what comes back from MySQL, yes. Just thought I'd mention that.